# foreignObject overflow:visible not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to make my drawing application work well in Firefox.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
.list {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
.list-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
}
foreignObject {
  overflow: visible;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="300" height="200" fill="blue">
<foreignObject width="300" height="25">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-item">a</div>
    <div class="list-item">b</div>
    <div class="list-item">c</div>
  </div>
</foreignObject>
  </svg>
  <svg class="svg2" width="300" height="200" fill="blue">
<foreignObject width="300" height="25">
  <div class="list">
  </div>
</foreignObject>
  </svg>
  <script>
let svg = document.querySelector('.svg2');
svg.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
function handleMouseMove(e) {
  console.log(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
}
setTimeout(() => {
  let el = document.querySelector('.svg2 .list');
  let a = document.createElement('div')
  let b = document.createElement('div');
  let c = document.createElement('div');
  a.innerHTML = 'a';
  b.innerHTML = 'b';
  c.innerHTML = 'c';
  a.classList.add('list-item')
  b.classList.add('list-item')
  c.classList.add('list-item')
  el.appendChild(a);
  el.appendChild(b);
  el.appendChild(c);
}, 1000);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In Chrome, both svg show all 3 items.

In Firefox(developer version 78.0b4 (64-bit)), in the first svg, all 3 items are visible, in the second svg, only the first item is visible. Why does the second svg not show all 3 items?

Comment: You can set the foreignObject style.overflow inside the setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

Setting `style="overflow: visible"` on `<svg>` solved the same issue for me.

SVG and sub-elements also support `overflow="visible"` as an attribute (so you can try `<foreignObject overflow="visible ... >`).